# Autowire a Repository to a library project in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-mongodb, spring-modules

I'm working on a Spring Boot multi-module project. I have created separate modules as follows

- `com.foodshop.api` - (this is a Spring Boot project, the starting point and both `com.foodshop.application` and `com.foodshop.persistence` are added as dependencies here)
- `com.foodshop.application` - (the application layer where I have the business logic, thi s is a library project and `spring-boot-starter` and `com.foodshop.persistence` are added as dependencies here)
- `com.foodshop.persistence` - (this is where the repositories defined, `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` is added as a dependency in this project)

All 3 project mentioned above are wrapped inside a parent `pom` maven project and the parent `pom.xml` looks as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.foodshop</groupId>
    <artifactId>foodshop-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>foodshop.persistence</module>
        <module>foodshop.application</module>
        <module>foodshop.api</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

The project builds without any errors. The application class of `foodshop.api` I have annotated as follows so that it can see the dependencies in other modules

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.foodshop"})
```

But when I try to run the API project, it looks like the `foodshop.application` fails to find and autowire the repositories defined in `foodshop.persistence`

I get an error as follows;

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.foodshop.application.MealManager required a bean of type 'com.foodshop.persistence.repository.MealRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.foodshop.persistence.repository.MealRepository' in your configuration.
```

I have properly annotated `MealRepository` with the `@Repository` annotation but I feel like I have missed something important.

It would be very much appreciated if I can get some help on this issue.

Comment: And it's supposed that you annotated the 'com.foodshop.persistence.repository.MealRepository' bean, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct @EvgeniEnchev

Comment: Just to be clear - you set the `@Repository` annotation on the implementation of the `com.foodshop.persistence.repository.MealRepository`, not on the interface. I had some errors and spent lot of time looking at the code when the annotation was not on the right place.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev Just to be clear - this is what I have done;

`@Repository
public interface MealRepository extends MongoRepository<Meal, String> {
}`

I don't see a need to implement a repository since I'm using Spring Data so I have annotated the Interface. Have I done something that I shouldn't have done?

Comment: Everything looks fine. Sorry, about the questions, didn't mention you use spring-data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more than 20 hours reading and following the trial and error approach, I was able to identify the issue. As per the [Spring official documentations](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/)

> If your application also uses JPA or Spring Data, the @EntityScan and
> @EnableJpaRepositories (and related) annotations inherit only their
> base package from @SpringBootApplication when not explicitly
> specified. That is, once you specify scanBasePackageClasses or
> scanBasePackages, you might also have to also explicitly use
> @EntityScan and @EnableJpaRepositories with their package scans
> explicitly configured.

Since I use `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`, I annotated my Application class as follows;

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.foodshop"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.foodshop.persistence")
public class Application {
  // main method goes here.
}
```

`@EnableMongoRepositories` annotation did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

This answer also works for JPA using @EnableJpaRepositories("com.dao.package")

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights. If this is the case here, please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it